# Search through Hashmap and add results to a List

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I'm doing a project for college and have hit a wall with how to search through my hashmap and add the results to a List.

So far i have  a Recommendation class with these variables as well as getters,setters constructor and hashcode and equals :

```
private String title, queryName,Director,summary,myComments,category;
private double Rating;
private int myRating;
private ArrayList<String> cast = new ArrayList<>();
```

So what i want to do is search through this map of Recommendations for an actors name and add the results to a List. This is what i've done so far : 
    private Map recs = new HashMap<>();

```
public void byActor(String actor)
{

    if(recs.containsKey(actor))
    {

        System.out.println(" The Actor "+actor + " has been in these films ");

    }
```

If the actor isn't in the hashmap i have to get recommendations off a website API,which should return it as a list or recommendations and add it to the hashmap ( which will be a local store )

How do I add the results of the search to a list and add a list to a hashmap?

Comment: What do you mean by `should return it as a list`? A `list` of `Recommendation`?

Comment: @aUserHimself hi sorry Yes its a list of Recommendations. Ill edit to add that in  :)

Comment: What does `actorMap` holds? Is it the response from the website API?

Comment: Oh i though i had commented that out sorry.

Comment: I was going to use a hashmap but i miss read the question and thought i was supposed to add it to another map.

Comment: So `recs` is the local store with all actor names and the list of recommendation for each actor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142095/discussion-between-auserhimself-and-emilyp).

Comment: @EmilyP you should always strive to have good variable names. `recs` is not very descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are supposed to create a local store containing a map of actor names and a list of Recommendations (I probably would named Recommendation Movie).

**Method to create local store**

```
public Map<String, List<Recommendation>> localStoreOfMovies() {

  // Call an API based on actor names, or maybe you have local list
  Map<String, List<Recommendation>> localStore = 
         new HashMap<String, List<Recommendation>>();

  List<Recommendation> movies = new List<Recommendation>();
  // Add robert de niro movies to movies list 
  localStore.put("robertdeniro",  movies);

  return localStore;
 }
```

**Get list of Recommendation based on actor**

If you are able to create the local store and create a map of actors, and list of recommendations, getting the list based on actor becomes simple, you can just do

```
public List<Recommendation> byActor(String actor) {
    // all movies are coming from instance local store
    return localStore.get(actor);
}
```

Comment: ok so my answer should work, you iterate over the all movies list, Which is probably an instance variable ? and then have a nested for loop to check the cast to see if the actor contains the name of the actor passed to `byActor` method. if it contains add to new list and return after you've looped through all recomnedations.

Comment: The question says : Each time an actors name is entered, the system will look for that name in the local store (Hash Map). I think i have to somehow search the hashmap of recommendations ( which is stored in a file ) to see if the actor is in cast(an ArrayList)  then add the results to a list. So i think i have to iterate through the hashmap?

Comment: @EmilyP so you have a local store of a hashmap, of <string, Recommendation> ? the key is the actors name ? if this is the case each actor will only have one recommendation (movie).. 

You mentioned this is an assignment where you given code before hand or just instructions on what must be done ?

Comment: @EmilyP take a look at my new answer.

Comment: Okay so i was just given instructions. I made the recommendation class and  a hashmap for it. Map<String,Recommendation> actorMap = new HashMap<>();           (first time using hashmaps so im not sure what i do to make the key actor? The question says You are required to write an application that provides Netflix recommendations based on a chosen actor stored in a local data store (cache).

Comment: This looks like the closest to what i need. Thank you for helping me : )

Comment: ok so all map means is there is a key and a value. If you have an arrayList of actors. You have to iterate through it and make the name of the actor key, and the value has to be a list, since an actor will have multiple movies so you have to modify the list and add the new movie if the actor exists other wise create new entry with the actor, and new list with movie.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to have a list of `Recommendation`s for each actor in your map, you need a `Map<String, List<Recommendation>>`. This is called a *multimap*.

```
Map<String, List<Recommendation>> recommendationsByActor = new HashMap<>();
```

If you are using Java 8, you can use the [`computeIfAbsent` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to add a recommendation for an actor, as follows:

```
recommendationsByActor
    .computeIfAbsent(actorName, k -> new ArrayList<>())
    .add(recommendation);
```

This will get the list of recommendations for an actor, if there were already one or more recommendations for that actor in the map. If there were no recommendations for that actor yet, `computeIfAbsent` will create an empty `ArrayList` for that actor and will put it into the map. *In both cases, the given recommendation will be added to the list of recommendations for that actor*.

If you just want to get the list of recommendations for a given actor, simply do:

```
List<Recommendation> recommendations = recommendationsByActor.get(actorName);
```

This will return the list of the recommendations for a given actor, or `null` if there are no recommendations for him/her.

**EDIT:**

If instead of creating an empty `ArrayList` for an actor who has no recommendations in the map, you need to get recommendations off a website API, you can change the call to `computeIfAbsent` as follows:

```
List<Recommendation> recommendations = recommendationsByActor
    .computeIfAbsent(actorName, this::getRecommendationsForActorFromWebAPI);
```

Where `getRecommendationsForActorFromWebAPI` would be an instance method in the same class, with the following signature:

```
private List<Recommendation> getRecommendationsForActorFromWebAPI(String actorName) {

    // TODO do the dirty work: call API and return recs list for actor
}
```

In this case, `computeIfAbsent` will return the list of recommendations for the given actor, either locally from the map (if the list is already present), or it will get the list of recommendations from the API call and add it to the map for that actor, before returning it.

Comment: Oh, I never noticed `computeIfAbsent` and always handled my multimaps with an if. Thanks for that, sir.

Answer (score 0):

To add a data on a list

```
myList.add(myData);
```

to add a data from a list to a map :

```
myMap.put(myKey, myValue);
```

if you want to add every data from the list :

```
for(dataType data : myList){ // this is a foreach
  myMap.put(myKey, myValue);
}
```

Cheers